# Add Database to Android Application

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm new to Android App development and programming. To be precise, I'm 1 day experienced in this domain! I've programmed a user registration page for my Android app. I don't know how to save the credentials entered by a user into a Database. I know how to create database in SQL and read that we can use SQLlite in Android App development. Where should we write the SQL code and where to save it and how do we link that code to Android app? I have MainActivity.java file. Is this the right place for me to start creating database? I'm sorry, I'm really dumb in this topic. Please advise.

Comment: Go through - http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[developer.android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) check this out.. such a small data should be stored in `Shared Preferences`, As you are new to technology try to solve problem yourself before asking such questions. Google is your tool..